# Have an issue using .htaccess to change HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a site with loads of html files but some of them require little PHP functions. I have heard that .htaccess can handle this and I tried the code below ...

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

... but when I do this if I open an page it asks me to download the .PHP file

Comment: Could you provide some more info on your env??

Comment: well I need to enable mod_php apparently. I have not been able to do it because my WHM/cPanel doesn't have mod_php as an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This suggests that you do not have mod_php installed or enabled.

The web server needs to know *how* to handle PHP as well as what files you want it to handle as PHP.

Comment: thanks. Do you happen to know how I enable it? I am using WHM/cPanel

Comment: I've never gone anywhere near cPanel.